# Set file association with flags in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, file-association

I would like to change a file association in Windows 7. I want to set the file to open with Google Chrome, however I want to pass through the `-incognito` flag to the exe so it defaults to incognito mode.

When I try to pass through the path to chrome `C:\Users\jon3laze\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -incognito` 
I get a *File not found* error.

I also tried creating a shortcut to the chrome.exe and setting the path to use incognito. This works if I execute the shortcut directly, however when I point the file association to the shortcut it still opens the file in an already opened (not incognito) chrome window.

How can I go about forcing a file association to use GC incognito?

**Update**

---

I tried changing the file association using `assoc` I found the information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184082)
It also did not work. I think the issue is that, if chrome is already open. It will default to the already open chrome rather than open in incognito. I would like to set specific file types such as `.jpg` or `.pdf` for this.

The file types now correctly have the `--incognito` flag associated to them, however don't open in an incognito window...even if all chrome windows are closed.

I tried duplicating the `chrome.exe`, renaming it and having the shortcut point to that with the flags instead. It seems the file properties showing that the original file is `chrome.exe` makes it continue to associate the files to the original.

Comment: Great Question.

Comment: Try adding a `​  --  ​` between the command-line args and the filename; that’s the command-line with which Chrome registers filetypes (though on my own system, I’ve left it out without issue).

Comment: I still run into the same issue. The file opens up in an already open, non incognito, window instead of opening a new incognito window.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.
3. Under `Classes`, open the `.html` key (folder) and note what the "`(Default)`" value is set to. Most likely it'll be `ChromeHTML`.
4. Go back to `Classes` and open the key you noted in #2.
5. Open the `shell\open\command` subkey.

   (At this step you should be at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`.)
6. Double-click the `(Default)` value and change its data to

   ```
   "C:\Users\jon3laze\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito -- %1
   ```

Comment: How would you go about doing this for different file types other than `.html`? For example, if I wanted `.pdf` or `.jpg` to default to incognito but everything else to use normal mode?

Comment: @jon3laze: If you have `.pdf` and `.jpg` associated with Chrome (unusual, I might say), follow steps 1-6. But you cannot set such rules for any random address you browse on the internets; this is *only* about what process is launched upon double-clicking a file on Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

NirSoft's [File Types Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) is a very convenient way to edit file type associations with flags/parameters, without having to lurk through lots of subfolders in the registry.

I tried setting a .pdf incognito association as you were trying to do, and it worked no problem.

You can do other things as well, such as quickly add or remove right click context menu items (i.e. "Edit in Notepad++"). Whenever you need to manage something clunky in Windows, I recommend always checking [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) first. They have a huge amount of useful utility programs.